# VLC-LUA: Extension does not respond - dialog box

Tags: lua, vlc

I have written an extension that works. The only annoying part is, that I get:

```
Extension 'SplitVideo' does not respond.
Do you want to kill it now?
```

This is because this line takes many seconds to run:

```
os.execute("splitvideo " .. secs .. " " .. file)
```

So simply waiting makes everything work as expected.

Is there a way I can tell VLC that "everything is fine - just be patient"?

Comment: ```os.execute()``` returning not what ```splitvideo``` is returning. But ```io.popen()``` do that. So give ```io.popen("splitvideo " .. secs .. " " .. file):read("*a")``` a try.